# Problems with Exporter in p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the next problems:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable id="table" var="EntradaVehiculo" value="#{allEntradasVehiculosMB.entradaVehiculos}"
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {Exporters}"
                 paginator="true" rows="10" style="margin-bottom:20px">

        <f:facet name="header">vehiculos</f:facet>

        <f:facet name="{Exporters}">
            <h:commandLink>
                <p:graphicImage name="img/xml.png" />
                <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="table" fileName="cars"/>
            </h:commandLink>
        </f:facet>

        <p:column headerText="" style="width:1px;">
            <h:outputText  style="display:none;"  id="id_entrada" value="#{EntradaVehiculo.idEntradaVehiculoPatio}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column filterBy="#{EntradaVehiculo.vehiculo.placaVehiculo}" style="width:110px;" headerText="Placa Vehiculo" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputText id="placa" value="#{EntradaVehiculo.vehiculo.placaVehiculo}"/>
        </p:column>
</h:form>
```

But the next part:

```
<f:facet name="{Exporters}">
    <h:commandLink>
        <p:graphicImage name="img/xml.png" width="24"/>
        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tbl" fileName="cars"/>
    </h:commandLink>
</f:facet>
```

The output showed bad.

In the part `{Exporter}`, only show the text `{Exporter}`.

[View example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNIiF.png):

[image]

and this should show the image of img/xml.png

Comment: Do you precisely have that image `xml.png` in the `img` directory under the `resources` directory which in turn should be under the web application root?

Comment: yes my image is in resources/img/xml.png !!! but I don't understand because only show the text {Exporter}.

Comment: this is my resources:

https://plus.google.com/u/0/109053684939655322938/posts/E4dsoufxVVy?pid=6097784014353704546&oid=109053684939655322938

Comment: what pf version are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using the next version: 

                <dependency>
   <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
   <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
   <version>5.0</version>
  </dependency>

It's my configuration maven of my project

Comment: The export there isn't problems, because I add the code for export under of my table and showed the image. The problems is when I use it within datables...

help me please, I want to have it good.. !!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your helps. 
The problems was the version of primeFaces, I add in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId> 
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId> 
    <version>5.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

and all good.

Thanks rion18.. !!!